# How to get nearby cities with CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cllocationmanager

I know how to get the current city but I need also the nearby city names...

```
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() // start updating location
            locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
            currentLocation = self.locationManager.location != nil ? self.locationManager.location : nil
            if currentLocation != nil{ 
                geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(currentLocation, completionHandler: {
                    placemarks, error in

                    if error == nil && placemarks!.count > 0 {
                        let placeArray = placemarks as [CLPlacemark]?
                        // Place details
                        let placeMark: CLPlacemark! = placeArray?[0]

                        // City
                        if let city = placeMark.addressDictionary?["City"] as? NSString {
                            self.city = city as String
                        }


                    }
                })

            }
```

I need a similar functionality to retrieve the near by city names.. Is there a way to use CLLocationManager to do that?
It seems there is no API to do that?   https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager

Comment: Maybe you can try looking into the GoogleMaps framework